# Using negative values in a bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

Starting with this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html), I would like to do something very similar but being able to use negative values for variables in the code, for example;

```
menMeans   = (-20, 35, -30, 35, -27)
womenMeans = (25, -32, 34, -20, 25)
```

, although this has nothing to do with the men/women meaning. But when I do this, I can not see anything related with negative values in the plot. I also change Y scale;

```
plt.yticks(np.arange(-81,81,10))
```

but nothing. Any hints?

Comment: I see the negative values there just fine, making the same changes you have ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change the `y` axis scale by the following command:

```
plt.ylim([-81,81])
```

which will set the `y` axis scale from -81 to 81

for the `x` scale axis that would be

```
plt.xlim([ xmin,xmax])
```

Answer (score 0):

in the gallery example you find this line of code:

```
plt.bar(ind, womenMeans, width, color='y',bottom=menMeans, yerr=menStd)
```

the value for the bottom can be chosen negative so that the bar starts from somewhere negative and is `womenMeans` long.

a yellow bar 
from -200 to 20 
at x=5 
with width = 10

would be:

```
plt.bar(5, 220,10, color='y',bottom=-200)
```